# deconflict ng-model for repeated ionic range input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using a series of range inputs to adjust the values on an object in `$scope`. Whilst my object is possibly not the best structure, it is what I have inherited and have to work with it as there is an app in the wild with this currently as a format.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Taylorsuk/pen/bEzPMN?editors=1010).

My object is structured like this:

```
{
    "exerciseID": "442",
    "exerciseName": "4 Point Kneeling Lumbar Flexion",
    "Params": [{
      "childParam": "",
      "param": "Reps"
    }, {
      "childParam": "",
      "param": "Sets"
    }]
  }
```

And my range inputs like so:

```
  <div ng-repeat="paramObj in activeExercise.Params track by $index">
    <div class="item item-divider">
      {{paramObj.param}}: {{activeExercise.paramters.paramObj.childParam}}
    </div>
    <div class="item range">
      <i class="icon orange" ng-class="paramClass(paramObj.param)"></i>
      <input type="range" name="parameter" min="0" ng-model="activeExercise.paramters.paramObj.childParam"  max="100" value="0">
      <i class="icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Regardless of what `ng-model` used I find I am unable to update the `childParam` values without changing the structure of the object, I am also unable to separate the two sliders so they can be changed independently.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ngRepeat` part should be just

```
ng-model="paramObj.childParam"
```